# Cannot instantiate proxy of class error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a simple unit test where when creating a Course, the Title field cannot be empty. I am having to test it with a service class that has Dependency Injection with UnitOfWork. When I debug my test, I am getting an Exception error of `Can not instantiate proxy of class: ContosoUniversity.Models.CourseRepository` I looked into the error, but am not able to understand how to fix the issue and the Assert statement?

[Error Message Display Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp18F.png)

**CourseRepository**

```
public class CourseRepository : GenericRepository<Course>
{
    public CourseRepository(SchoolContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
{
    private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
    private GenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    public CourseRepository CourseRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.courseRepository == null)
            {
                this.courseRepository = new CourseRepository(context);
            }
            return courseRepository;
        }
    }

    public virtual CourseRepository GetCourseRepository()
    {
        if (this.courseRepository == null)
        {
            this.courseRepository = new CourseRepository(context);
        }
        return courseRepository;
    }
```

**CourseService**

```
public class CourseService : ICourseService
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public CourseService (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void Create(Course course)
    {
        unitOfWork.GetCourseRepository().Insert(course);
        unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    public Course GetCourseByID(int id)
    {
        return unitOfWork.GetCourseRepository().GetByID(id);
    }
```

**TestMethod**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var course = new Course
    {
        CourseID = 2210,
        Title = string.Empty,
        Credits = 3,
        DepartmentID = 1
    };

    Mock<CourseRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<CourseRepository>();
    mockRepo.Setup(m => m.GetByID(course.CourseID)).Returns(course);

    var mockUnit = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mockUnit.Setup(x => x.GetCourseRepository()).Returns(mockRepo.Object);

    var myService = new CourseService(mockUnit.Object);
    myService.Create(course);

    //var error = _modelState["Title"].Errors[0];
    //Assert.AreEqual("The Title field is required.", error.ErrorMessage);

    //mockRepo.Setup(x => x.Insert(course));
}
```

Answer (score 101):

The error says that the `CourseRepository` can not be initialized because it does not have parameter less constructor. Mocking framework looks for parameter less constructor first to create mock object.

If your class does not have parameterless constructor then you need to pass those parameters when you create Mock. In your case mock of `CourseRepository` would be created as following.

```
var repositoryMock = new Mock<CourseRepository>(null);
```

Instead of null, you can pass mock objects of the constructor parameters also.

Comment: Should be noted that the preferred approach is to mock your interfaces, not your implementations. (`var repositoryMock = new Mock<ICourseRepository>();`)

Comment: Correct @Riscie. But if interfaces are not used, concrete classes need to be mocked.

Comment: Totally correct @ChetanRanpariya. I just wanted to mention it because it is easy to overlook.

Comment: For consistency we should mock only interfaces, but mock interfaces do not accept parameters `Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks.`. Any solutions?

Comment: Interfaces do not have constructor so you should not be worrying about that @MihaiSocaciu. The focus should be on how to mock the behavior of methods of interface.

Comment: For me all solutions error out. I asked a detailed question on how to use Unit of Work and unit tests. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77524115/9442199

Answer (score 6):

Just use the interface when mocking.

```
Mock<ICourseRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<ICourseRepository>();
mockRepo.Setup(m => m.GetByID(course.CourseID)).Returns(course);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if your class has an **internal** parameterless constructor, you need to add the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to assembly.

In case of Moq, add this:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

Or this, if you need an strong key

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2,PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100c547cac37abd99c8db225ef2f6c8a3602f3b3606cc9891605d02baa56104f4cfc0734aa39b93bf7852f7d9266654753cc297e7d2edfe0bac1cdcf9f717241550e0a7b191195b7667bb4f64bcb8e2121380fd1d9d46ad2d92d2d15605093924cceaf74c4861eff62abf69b9291ed0a340e113be11e6a7d3113e92484cf7045cc7")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mock the interface Mock instead of concrete class Mock

Answer (score -1):

In my case, adding the `[Frozen]` attribute to my mock helped solve this problem.

I was also having the "cannot instantiate proxy of class error", but in my case, I was doing something like this:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqDate]
public async void Should_DoThis_When_ThatHappens(
    Fixture fixture,
    Mock<TroublesomeClass> troublesomeObject
){
    var someResult = SomeObject();

    troublesomeObject.Setup(o => o.SomeMethodAsync().ReturnsAsync(someResult);

    // Code bellow is irrelevant...

}
```

For me, troublesomeObject's method was called in my suite's method, and when it got to SomeMethodAsync() is when the exception occurred.
When I added the [Frozen] tag before the troublesome object, the issue subsided.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Create an empty Parameterless constructor for your `CourseRepository` class, so that Mock can use:

```
public CourseRepository() {}
```

Comment: you should never create separate code path that's just for testing! Dependency Inversion is the right approach as Interface can be automatically created without parameter.